# Probability that two values drawn at random from a normal distribution are separated by at most T

Tags: normal-distribution, sample

I need a closed-form expression for the probability that 2 values drawn at random from a normal distribution are separated by at most T, as a function of T and the variance of the distribution. I can formulate the problem as an integration, but can't solve it. I'd be happy with a well-motivated approximation. I'd be amenable to making some simplifying assumptions about the distribution, if that would help.

Answer (score 10):

The distribution of the difference between two single independent samples from normal distributions has a mean which is the difference between the means of the original distributions and a variance which is the sum of the variances of the original distributions.

So in your case, if the normal distribution of $X$ has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ then $X_1-X_2$ has a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $2\sigma^2$; if you prefer,$\frac{X_1-X_2}{\sqrt{2} \sigma}$ has a standard normal distribution.  So long as you do a two-tailed calculation, that should be enough for you to find your answer.

To spell it out, your answer should be 
$$2 \Phi \left(\frac{T}{\sqrt{2} \sigma} \right) - 1$$
where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal distribution.

Comment: +1, nice answer. Of course there's still an integral hiding in there ;)

Comment: @JMS In some sense there are integrals hiding in many formulas.  For instance, the logarithm is usually defined as an integral.  Many other functions, like the exponential and the functions of mathematical physics, are (or can be) defined as solutions of differential equations--that is, generalizations of integrals.

Comment: @whuber Of course you're right; I was just poking a little fun. Although there is the somewhat larger point that we shouldn't be afraid of integrals we can't solve analytically if we can approximate them well as is the case for $\Phi$ above, or as you mention the menagerie of special functions arising from differential equations.

Comment: @JMS Yep, that's exactly the point I was trying to provoke :-)  (I only wish I were as comfortable with, say, hypergeometric and theta functions as I am with trig and exponential functions...)